# Addslashes, mysql_real_escape always adding two slashes?

Tags: php, addslashes

I'm having an issue with inserting JSON into a database, my intention is to take the variables, json_encode them, remove slashes (from magic_quotes), and then addslashes back in to escape the quotes in {"key":"value"}

Unfortunately, strip_slashes on the encoded string isn't doing anything, and outputs this

```
{"content":"<p>This string has it\'s downsides</p>","date":1271352514}
```

I have then tried addslashes, and mysql_real_escape_string, both output

```
"{\\"content\\":\\"<p>This string has it\\\'s downsides</p>\\",\\"date\\":1271352514}"
```

I can't work out why it's adding in two slashes? And I'm tearing my hair out over this, everytime I try to stripslashes it leaves one in, and adding slashes adds two. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Well, `magic_quotes` should be turned off. Security wise, it SHOULD be off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should really consider turning `magic_quotes` off... To quote [the manual](http://php.net/magicquotes):

> ### Warning
>
> This feature has been ***DEPRECATED*** as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

---

That being said, use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) to build your JSON array (instead of building your own), and finish off with a single call to [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) while querying as such:

```
$data = array();
$data['content'] = "<p>This string has it's downsides</p>";
$data['date'] = 1271352514;

$json = json_encode($data);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO data
                VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($json) . "');");
```

---

Also, the PHP group recommends you use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli) instead of [`mysql`](http://php.net/mysql). Its Object Oriented API and support for parametrized queries greatly improve both development speed, code maintenance and security.

Here is the above code written using [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli):

```
$data = array();
$data['content'] = "<p>This string has it's downsides</p>";
$data['date'] = 1271352514;

$json = json_encode($data);

$sqlInsert = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO data VALUES (?);")
$sqlInsert->bind_param("s", $json);
$sqlInsert->execute();
```

Comment: At the moment, I can't turn off magic_quotes because there are several sites on the server, and simply turning it off could cause a fair few problems.

I am already using json_encode. I create a new file, with a json encoded array, and I use mysql_escape_string it works fine. But within the context of the script, the exact same strings are adding in two slashes instead of just one.

Comment: @Zach: You even have `magic_quotes_runtime` on? Oh boy... Enjoy. I can't help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a JSON string like this (by the way: In JSON the `/` needs to be escaped too):

```
{"content":"<p>This string has it\'s downsides<\/p>","date":1271352514}
```

Then you just need to apply [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) on it to escape it so that it can be used to insert it into a MySQL string declaration:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO … SET json='".mysql_real_escape_string($json).'"';
```

And if you have Magic Quotes enabled, you should [disable or remove them](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) before that step so that your `$json` string is really just valid JSON.